# responsive Google chart only shows up after first resize

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

I have a Google line chart which doesn't show up after loading the page. After the first resize everything works.
How can I get the chart show up after loading the page?

Data comes from locale text file on the server. This textfile holds the date/time and a sensor value. Textfile gets split and used as data for the chart.

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    function drawChart () {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'Temp.ESP',
          type: 'get',
          success: function (txt) {
              var dataArray = [['Name', 'Date']];
              var txtArray = txt.split('\n');
              for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {
                  var tmpData = txtArray[i].split(/\s+/);
                  dataArray.push([tmpData[0], parseInt(tmpData[1])]);
              }
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
              var options = {width: '100%',
                             height: '40%',
                             legend: 'none',
                             colors: ['red'],
                             hAxis: {
                                    textStyle:{color: 'white'}},
                            vAxis: {
                                    textStyle:{color: 'white'}},
                             backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }};
              $(window).resize(function(){
                chart.draw(data,options);
              });
          }
      });
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
    
    setInterval(function(){ 
            $.get( "mydata.php", function( data ) {
                $( "#mydata" ).html( data ); // this will replace the html refreshing its content using ajax
            });
        }, 1000);
```

```css
/* Chart */
    #chart{
        width: 100%; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="chart">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to call the draw function.

First call was in the resize function.

```js
function drawChart () {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'Temp.ESP',
          type: 'get',
          success: function (txt) {
              var dataArray = [['Name', 'Date']];
              var txtArray = txt.split('\n');
              for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {
                  var tmpData = txtArray[i].split(/\s+/);
                  dataArray.push([tmpData[0], parseInt(tmpData[1])]);
              }
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
              var options = {width: '100%',
        height: '40%',
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['red'],
        hAxis: {
         textStyle:{color: 'white'}},
       vAxis: {
         textStyle:{color: 'white'}},
        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }};
        
        chart.draw(data,options); //forgot this call
        
              $(window).resize(function(){
    chart.draw(data,options);
     });
          }
      });
```

Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what's going on without being able to run your code, but it could just be a simple css fix. Try changing the parent to a flex container at 100vw and the child chart at flex:1

```
#chart{
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  // adjust the padding accordingly
}

#chart_div {
  flex: 1;
}
```